# Understanding SendAsync method ASP.net web API Message Handlers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to implement a custom Message Handler, below is the code.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        /* Code that executes while receiving the request - start */
        bool isBadrequest = false;

        if (isBadrequest)
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound,"test");
        }
       /* Code that executes while receiving the request - end */

       /* Code that executes while sending the response - start */            
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request , cancellationToken);
        response.Headers.Add("new header", "new header value");
        return response;
       /* Code that executes while sending the response - end */
    } 
}
```

I am aware of Tasks and async/await in C#.
But I am unable to understand how the same method gets executed both while receiving the request and sending the response.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) is right from the asp.net website and explains how ***SendAsync*** works.

The method takes an **HttpRequestMessage** as input and asynchronously returns an **HttpResponseMessage**. A typical implementation does the following:

1. Process the request message.
2. Call base.SendAsync to send the request to the inner handler.
3. The inner handler returns a response message. (This step is
   asynchronous.)
4. Process the response and return it to the caller.

Here is a trivial example:

```
public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, here is a [great article](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi) about how to log request and response messages using a message handler.